# How to find the particular solution of $dx = (2y-x)dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the particular solution of $dx = (2y-x)dy$ but I can't find a way to move x and dx on one side and y and dy on the other side. I know that this is a simple question but it seems that I just can't find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. It should be (2y-x)dy.

Comment: This is an ordinary differential equation, not a partial differential equation. You can write it as a linear differential equation for $x$ as a function of $y$.

Comment: I need to move dy along with all $y$s on one side and everything else on the other side, then integrate the both sides and find C. Not sure on how to do that.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If the goal is to solve the equation, then you don't have to do that, you can just do what I said to do. If the goal isn't to solve the equation, then????

Comment: From what I understand, that's the way that I need to solve this equation from the book. It's a particular solution for a multivariable differential equation.

Comment: In that case, you lose. Your equation is not "variables-separable". What you say you need to do, can't be done. You might be able to do it if you first introduce a new variable $v=2y-x$, and then rewrite it as an equation in $v$ and $y$.

Comment: This is not separable, not exact. So I think you have to find an *integrating factor* to make it exact

Answer (score 1):

$$dx = (2y-x)dy$$
Rewrite it as:
$$x'+x=2y$$
$$(xe^y)'=2ye^y$$
Integrate.

---

If you only need the particular solution of the DE, you can try this :
$$x_p=Ay+B$$
Where $A,B$ are constants.

Answer (score 0):

This *answer*, which took me some time, is (in effect) a very inelegant trodding
on the path very similar to Aryadeva's answer.  Everything below presumes that
Aryadeva's elegant answer doesn't exist.

---

I agree with Gerry Myerson.  However, based on my *bible*, Calculus Vol 1,
2nd Ed. (1966 : Apostol), this is something of a **trick question** (at least
from the perspective of someone with an undergraduate level comprehension of
Real Analysis).

Apostol solves $y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$, where $f(a) = b$

by $f(x) = be^{-A(x)} + e^{-A(x)}\int_a^x Q(t)e^{A(t)}dt,$

where $A(x) = \int_a^x P(t)dt.$

The original equation $dx = (2y - x)dy$ translates into 
$x' = (2y - x),$ where $x'$ represents $dx/dy.$

Consequently, I attack the problem by construing $x = g(y)$, rather than $y = f(x).$

Under this construance:

$x' + P(y)x = Q(y)$, where 
$P(y) = 1$ and $Q(y) = 2y.$

Here, $A(y) = \int_a^y 1dt = (y - a).$

Next, $\int_a^y Q(t)e^{A(t)}dt = \int_a^y 2te^{(t-a)}dt.$
Integration by parts resolves this to $(2t - 2) e^{(t - a)}$ 
evaluated at $t = y$ and $t = a$, which resolves to 
$(2y-2)e^{(y-a)} - (2a - 2).$

This yields 
$g(y) = be^{(a-y)} + e^{(a-y)} \times [(2y-2)e^{(y-a)} - (2a - 2)].$

With no initial value condition imposed, $b$ and $a$ are *any* arbitrary
constants.  Therefore, the above expression collapses to 
$g(y) = be^{(a-y)} + (2y - 2).$

I don't have the knowledge or sophistication to determine whether this must be
converted into the $y = f(x)$ format, and (if so) how to do that.

Comment: As $y$ appears both in and out of the exponent, you won't have any luck writing this as $y=f(x)$, unless you accept use of the Lambert-W function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: @GerryMyerson got it, thanks.